# How to include external FTL inside a FTL

Tags: freemarker

I am including an external static FTL file (from a repository) into my project FTL using <#include> directive as below. But I am unable to insert this FTL. Can someone please guide me how to include external URLs.

```
<#include "http://{domain}/file.ftl" />
```

Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template "http://{domain}/file.ftl" not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a template need to be loaded (for `#include` or `Configuration.getTemplate`, etc.), FreeMarker calls the `TemplateLoader` of the `Configuration` to do that (unless the template is already in the cache). It's up to the `TemplateLoader` to interpret the address and actually load the template. There's no `TemplateLoader` included that loads from `http:` addresses, so you will need to create a custom `TemplateLoader` implementation that does that. Then set the `templateLoader` configuration setting to it.

Answer (score 0):

imagine there are *1 Parent* and *2 Children*;

There are possible cases to may handled:

- pass params from **Parent -> Child**
- pass params from **1st Child -> Parent -> 2nd Child**

My answer covers both of them:
in the Parent we import both childs and create a storage variable calling 'Path':

```
<#import "breadcrumbs.ftl" as breadcrumbs>

<#macro breadCrumbs path=[]>
    <@breadcrumbs.breadcrumbs path=path/>
</#macro>

<#macro wrap>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <div id="breadcrumbs">
    </html>
</#macro>
```

1st child we define as a Breadcrumb and it settles in a *div#breadcrumbs*

```
<#macro breadcrumbs path=[]>
    <#assign totalpath=["{'name': 'Home', 'url': '${appContext}/'}"] + path/>

    <script type="module">
        import {BreadCrumbs} from "${appContext}/_app/jsx/breadcrumbs.js";

        new BreadCrumbs({
            "containerID": "breadcrumbs",
            "path": [<#list totalpath as p>${p}, </#list>],
        });
    </script>
</#macro>
```

2nd child is

```
<#import "./admin-layout.ftl" as layout>

<@layout.wrap>
    <@layout.breadCrumbs path = ["{'name': 'Models', 'url':'${appContext}/admin/model'}"]/>
    <div>some other comntent</div>
</@layout.wrap>
```

**Conclusion**: 1st child adds to breadcrumns the source page and the 2nd child pushes to the path the rest of the crumbs

as a result we got:

[image]